# Does second order ZFC conservatively extend first order ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, proof-theory

1. If I replace the axiom schema of specification in ZFC by a single axiom in second order logic, and similarly do same thing for the axiom schema of replacement, is this version of "second order ZFC" stronger then the original one when it proves first order sentences?
2. If it is, is there any example proved in second order ZFC but not in first order ZFC?
3. If not, is there any effective algorithm to convert proof of first order sentence in second order ZFC to that in first order ZFC?
4. How about PA, or other axiomatic systems including axiom schema easily translated into single second order axiom? Is there any general result? If so, where can I find it?(reference?)

Thank you.

Edit

Andreas Blass commented that I didn't say anything about "deduction". So I post some rules of inference:

1. Modus Ponen
2. for sentence A, property P, function F, variable x, one can deduce "A for all P", "A for all F" and "A for all x" from "A"

Comment: Your first question refers to second-order logic "proving" things. Since second-order logic doesn't have a complete deductive system, you should say what you mean here by "proving". You might have a trivial variant of first-order logic, or you might be thinking of "consequence" rather than provability, or maybe something else.

Comment: @Andreas Blass You are absolutely right! I read about second order logic in the Mendelson's "Introduction to Mathematical Logic", so the proof system I intended was that described in the book. I'll edit my question to add rules of inference. Thank you!

Comment: Since you didn’t include any comprehension axioms in your second-order logic, this second-order version of ZFC is actually much *weaker* than ZFC, it’s effectively ZFC without replacement.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek I think I don't understand your answer yet. Did you mean "specification" by "comprehension"? I thought I could replace axiom schema of specification in original ZFC by one \axiom in second order logic. Did I miss something?

Comment: No, I meant comprehension. In order that the second-order replacement axiom implies the first-order replacement schema, you need to postulate at least that for every first-order formula $\phi(x)$, there exists a class (i.e., second-order object) whose extension is $\{x:\phi(x)\}$. You axiom system so far does not imply the existence of any second-order objects whatsoever.

Comment: @ Emil Jeřábek Now I got it. I think you are right. The problem was, in Mendelson's book, comprehension is assumed as a logical axiom of second-order predicate logic. So I implicitly assumed it. If we do so, does my question make sense?

Comment: You have to be precise. What class of formulas do you allow in comprehension? This is crucial to gauge the strength of the theory. On the one hand, if you have comprehension only for first-order formulas, or formulas with second-order parameters but no SO quantifiers, you get (a variant of) the NBG set theory, which is a conservative extension of ZFC. On the other hand, if you have comprehension for all SO formulas, you get the Kelly-Morse set theory, which is stronger.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek Oh I see. I would prefer the NBG-like one, so that question number 1 is answered as "no". Now question number 3: is there an effective algorithm to translate NBG proof into ZFC proof?

Comment: Now that is actually an interesting question. There is an algorithm, but its time complexity is iterated exponential (tetration). It is known that there is no [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY) algorithm.

Comment: @ Emil Jeřábek Wow that's.. awesome. But simply googling "NBG proof translation algorithm" doesn't find anything. Where can I find it?

Comment: And question number 4. How about PA, or any other FOL axiomatic systems with "simple enough" axiom schema? Is there general way to get "natural SOL conservative extension" from them?

Comment: The algorithm for conversion of NBG proofs to ZFC proofs works by cut elimination. This is a folklore result. It is briefly sketched (in another form using Herbrand’s theorem) in §4 of Pudlák’s *Cuts, consistency statements and interpretations* (J. Symb. Logic 50 (1985), pp. 423–441), where he also proves in detail the superexponential lower bound. This all works for any sequential theories axiomatized by finitely many schemata, such as PA, where the corresponding SO theory is $\mathit{ACA}_0$.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek I solved all the mysteries. Thank you so much...